# Can hurricanes set off earthquakes?

Tags: earthquakes, tropical-cyclone

Large hurricanes can show up on seismographs. Do they do this by shaking the ground with wind? Moving large amounts of water putting weight on the tectonic plates?

A large earthquake is the result of long term tectonic forces, but I wonder if local weather activity could trigger earthquakes?

Is this obviously impossible?